# Splitting the numerator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Can someone explain how we can get the second fraction by **splitting the numerator**?

$$\frac{x^3}{x^2+x+1}=x-1+\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$$

I can get the LHS from the RHS but not the other way around. What are the missing steps?

Answer (score 4):

Hint :

$x^3=(x^3-1)+1$ and $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

Answer (score 2):

Don't they teach long division in school anymore? sheesh

[image]

The remainder becomes the numerator in the fractional part of the mixed fraction
$$x - 1 +\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{x^3}{x^2+x+1}=\dfrac{x^3-1+1}{x^2+x+1}=\dfrac{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)+1}{x^2+x+1}=x-1+\dfrac{1}{x^2+x+1}$